# Регулярные выражения с негативным просмотром назад

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как найти в vsCode все вхождения `bc`, у которого предыдущий символ не `a`.
Пример:

```
dabc - bad
dbca - good
```

Я нашел как это сделать с "негативным просмотром назад".

```
(?<!a)bc
```

Но к сожалению это не работает в vsCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте захватывающую подмаску в регулярном выражении и обратную ссылку в шаблоне замены.

```
(^|[^a])bc
```

Если нужно удалить `bc`, замените на `$1`. Для замены на что-то другое, `$1<НОВЫЙ_ТЕКСТ>`.

Comment: не понял на счет замены? и можно ли исключить предыдущий символ из захвата?